# How to get raw User Timings data using Google Analytics Core Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using [User Timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings?hl=en) to measure how long something takes, by doing e.g. `ga('send', 'timing', 'jQuery', 'Load Library', 20, 'Google CDN');`

In Google Analytics web interface at *Behavior > Site Speed > User Timings* I can see both an average and an histogram (by clicking the tab Distribution).

Using the Analytics Core Reporting API I'm able to retrieve the average user timing by querying on the metric `ga:avgUserTimingValue`. I was wondering if it's possible to retrieve the histogram or the raw data itself. I'm specifically looking to create a box plot using the user timings data.

Comment: can export any report as a csv?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I guess it isn't possible. One trick could be to use regular events, misuse the event label as the event value, and to set every event value to 1. That way you can still retrieve raw data from Google Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Make an API request for the metric [ga:userTimingValue](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user_timings&jump=ga_usertimingvalue) together with the dimensions you want to split by such as [ga:date](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_date).

Or you can create a custom report with the **User Timing Value** as metric and **Date** as dimension